# what are the executable types on windows/cmd? and what are their priorities?

Tags: windows, command-line, executable

For example if there are multiple executable files on the path i.e., a.exe, a.bat and user types 'a' (enter), which file will execute?

What other executable formats are supported on Windows?

Comment: Thanks for your responses, but these are three different answers - which all look right. Could you all converge on one?

Comment: As for the first question ("what are the executable types") and the last question ("What other executable formats"), those outer questions (though not the middle question about priorities) are basically duplicated at the older [SuperUser: On Windows, what filename extensions denote an executable?](http://superuser.com/questions/228680/on-windows-what-filename-extensions-denote-an-executable/1182994#1182994).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows looks at the `PATHEXT` environment variable to decide which file types are considered executable:

```
> echo %PATHEXT%
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

The first matching file on the path that has one of those extensions will be executed.

You can use the `assoc` and `ftype` commands to find out how the file will be executed:

```
> assoc .msc
.msc=MSCFile

> ftype MSCFile
MSCFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\mmc.exe "%1" %*
```

(You can use `PATHEXT`, `assoc` and `ftype` to make any file type executable.)

Comment: Did you forget *.msi ?

Comment: @ComputerUser: Interesting!  I don't have `.msi` in my `PATHEXT` but Windows *does* search the `PATH` for them.  Obviously my answer is incomplete, but I don't know what's missing.

Answer (score 1):

Precedence is: DOSKEY Macro  .COM  .EXE  .BAT

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/35284

Comment: That answer is for MS-DOS.  Windows is different.

Comment: Nope; it’s the same for Windows.

Comment: According to the KB article, it only applies to MS-DOS 4.0 to 6.22.