# How do I open a WinSCP GUI session from command line?

Tags: winscp

If I have a session named "hpc" and I run:

```
winscp hpc
```

I get into command line mode. How do I run the GUI and open a session from the command line (Windows)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WinSCP has two executables, `winscp.exe` and `winscp.com`. The [`winscp.exe`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables#winscp.exe) is GUI, while the [`winscp.com`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables#winscp.com) is command-line.

If you use just the `winscp`, due to an [extension precedence in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7839150/850848), the `.com` wins. Make sure you use a full GUI executable name:

```
winscp.exe hpc
```

References:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline

Comment: Damn, I didn't pay attention. Thanks.